# Using esttab with ttest

Tags: latex, stata

I am running a `ttest` command and exporting results to LaTeX using `estpost` and the *community-contributed* command `esttab`.

I am testing for a difference for means (of variable `height`, by `child gender`) for several years and would like the years to be displayed *vertically* (in rows) rather than horizontally.

My code and is given below:

```
foreach i in 2009 2010 2013 {
    use "`i'.dta", clear
    global year `i'
    eststo _$year : estpost ttest height, by(child_gender)
}

esttab . using "trends.tex", nonumber append
```

Data for 2009:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(child_gender height)
0 156
1 135
0 189
1 168
0 157
1 189
1 135
1 145
0 124
1 139
end
```

Data for 2010:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(child_gender height)
0 151
1 162
0 157
1 134
0 157
1 189
1 135
1 145
0 143
1 166
end
```

Data for 2013:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(child_gender height)
0 177
0 135
0 189
0 168
0 157
1 189
1 135
1 145
1 124
1 127
end
```

I would like the output arranged as follows (but in `LaTeX`):

[image]

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this can be found below. You need to play with the options to further polish the table.

First define the program `append_ttests`, which is a quickly modified version of `appendmodels`, Ben Jann's [program for stacking models](http://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/estout/other.html):

```
program append_ttests, eclass
    version 8
    syntax namelist
    tempname b V tmp
    foreach name of local namelist {
        qui est restore `name'
        mat `tmp' = e(b)
        local eq1: coleq `tmp'
        gettoken eq1 : eq1
        mat `tmp' = `tmp'[1,"`eq1':"]
        local cons = colnumb(`tmp',"_cons")
        if `cons'<. & `cons'>1 {
            mat `tmp' = `tmp'[1,1..`cons'-1]
        }
        mat `b' = nullmat(`b') , `tmp'

        mat `tmp' = e(t)
        mat `tmp' = `tmp'["`eq1':","`eq1':"]
        if `cons'<. & `cons'>1 {
            mat `tmp' = `tmp'[1..`cons'-1,1..`cons'-1]
        }
        capt confirm matrix `V'
        if _rc {
            mat `V' = `tmp'
        }
        else {
            mat `V' = ///
            ( `V'  \ ///
             `tmp' )
        } 
    }
    mat `b' = `b''
    mat A = `b' , `V'
    mat rown A = `0'
    ereturn matrix results = A
    eret local cmd "append_ttests"
end
```

Then run your loop and append the t-tests:

```
foreach i in 2009 2010 2013 {
    use "`i'.dta", clear
    estpost ttest height, by(child_gender)
    estimates store year`i' 
 }

append_ttests year2009 year2010 year2013
```

See the results as follows:

```
esttab e(results), nonumber mlabels(none) ///
                   varlabels(year2009 2009 year2010 2010 year2013 2013) ///
                   collabels("Height" "t statistic")

--------------------------------------
                   Height  t statistic
--------------------------------------
2009             4.666667     .3036859
2010            -3.166667    -.2833041
2013                 21.2     1.415095
--------------------------------------
```

Add the `tex` option to see the `LaTeX` output.

Comment: May I ask how to install append_ttests? It doesnt work if we simply run the code in the same do file and then use append_ttests.